# jenkins pipeline with code: pause for input

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Can someone point me to good documentation for using jenkins pipeline as code ? below is what i am trying to achieve.

can anyone guide me to how to setup jenkins which will send email notification to approver for deploying the artifacts to next higher staging environment.

So basically we want once the build is completed and artifacts deployed to artifactory an email notification link should be sent out to Approver. Once approver click son link and click on approve the artifacts should be deployed to DeV once deployed to dev again and email notification should be sent out to approver. Once approver clicks on link and approves it the build artifacts should be deployed to TEST environment

can someone guide me on how can this be achieved

-thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We can't explain you just everything. There is the `input` step. Try to use it and add the other code around, then ask a new question when you run into a specific problem.

Answer (score 8):

**You will want to use the following 2 pipeline steps:**

1. [Email Extended](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/#emailext-extended-email)
2. [Input Step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/)

Within your pipeline script, you will notify your team of a build, and then wait for approval.

```
stage("Build") {
    // Run build
    emailext subject: "Approve Build" body: "Approve build with link"
    input message: "Approve build?" submitter: "admin_group"
}

stage("Deploy") {
    // deploy artifact (only gets run after approval)
}
```

The `submitter` parameter of `input` allows you to declare an active directory user or group which has permission to approve the build.

The **Deploy** stage does not get executed until the input approval is complete in the **Build** Stage.

An improvement would be to add timeout restrictions to the build approval with [Timeout Step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-timeout-code-enforce-time-limit)

Comment: Thank you very Much